# Execute script from string with accessing the variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, exec

I have a python script as a string, as example:

```
exec("sent = {'test': 1}")
global sent
print(sent)
```

I executed it using exec function, then I accessed the variable using `global` python command. This way works without problem without using classes, but when I have the same code in a class, like:

```
class example:
    def fun1(self):
        exec("sent = {'test': 1}")
        global sent
        print(sent)

v = example()
print(v.fun1())
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'sent' is not defined
```

Comment: Try: exec("global sent;sent = {}") . But avoid using global variables if you can.

Comment: I can't add "global" to the string, because it's too long

Comment: Ghanem: What do you mean it's too long? Strings can be almost any length in Python.

Comment: It's a dataset, someone build it in a code format .. "dummy way"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the global dictionary to modify. Try:

```
 exec("sent = {}",globals())
```

Comment: to make the question clear, I append a value to the "sent" variable

Comment: The original question was trying to initialize 'sent' to an empty array. This does that. you may also set 'send' to a given dictionary, as in the modified question by:

      exec("sent = {'test': 1}",globals())

or modify a dictionary that was previously defined as global:

      exec(" my_global_dictionary['new_key'] = 'new_value'", global())

but adding the second argument, a reference to the global dictionary is crucial. If you do not add this exec creates a global dictionary = {} which is discarded after the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

You really should avoid using global variables. Regardless, here's how to do it:

```
class example:
    def fun1(self):
#        globals sent  # Not needed in this special case.
        exec("sent = {}", globals())
        print('in fun1, "sent" is now', sent )


v = example()
print(v.fun1())  # Result will be None because fun1() doesn't return anything.
print('after call to fun1(), global "sent" is', sent)
```

Output:

```
in fun1, "sent" is now {}
None
after call to fun1(), global "sent" is {}
```

A `global` declaration only does something inside a function or class method and even then is only needed when the global variable's value is going to be set to something. 
However, as a special case, one isn't really needed here in the `fun1()` method because it explicitly passes `globals()` (but not a separate locals dict) when it calls `exec()`. It might be a good idea to put one in anyway to make it more clear what's going on.

Using `exec()` this way is explained in its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) which says:

> If only globals is provided, it must be a dictionary, which will be used for **both** the global and the local variables.

(emphasis mine)

Here's a way to avoid referencing a global variable at all in the method:

```
class example:
    def fun1(self):
        namespace = {}
        exec("sent = {}", namespace)
        sent = namespace['sent']  # Retrieve result.
        print('in fun1, "sent" is now', sent )
        return sent

v = example()
sent = v.fun1()
print('after calling fun1(), "sent" got set to', sent)
```

Output:

```
in fun1, "sent" is now {}
after calling fun1(), "sent" got set to {}
```

Comment: it didn't work, it prints "None .. regarding to: "You really should avoid using global variables", what is the alternative in such a case?

Comment: Ghanem: I think it works now, sorry about that. Alternatives to using globals depend on exactly what you're doing. The most common way is by passing them to the function/method as arguments (if they have mutable values). The other is by `return`ing them from the function/method. i.e. `sent = v1.fun1()` (assuming you also put a `return sent` statement at the end of the method).